# Error when using glLoadMatrix and glm.value_ptr()

Tags: python, opengl, glm-math, opengl-compat

I'm currently working on an FPS-style camera module in python using OpenGL and GLM. Using glm, I generate a view matrix with `gluLookAt()`. When I try to load it to OpenGL using `glm.value_ptr()`, it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'CtypesPointerHandler' object has no attribute 'arrayByteCount'", <function asArrayTypeSize.<locals>.asArraySize at 0x0000021D3BD0CD08>)
```

Here's my code:

```
viewMatrix = glm.lookAt(self.position, self.position + self.front, self.upVector)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrixf(glm.value_ptr(viewMatrix))
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and maybe explain what `glm.value_ptr()` returns exactly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're in Python, I'm not sure `value_ptr` is a useful thing.

Comment: `valu_ptr` works for `glUniform`*, `glBufferSubData` etc., but it does not work for `glLoadMatrixf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use PyOpenGL, then you have to convert the matrix to a list. See [PyOpenGL - `glLoadMatrix`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glLoadMatrix.html):

```py
viewMatrix = glm.lookAt(self.position, self.position + self.front, self.upVector)
```

```py
matList = [viewMatrix[i][j] for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrixf(matList)
```

---

Alternatively `glLoadMatrix` accepts a [`ctypes.c_float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) array. See [ctypes - Data types](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#data-types) e.g:

```py
matArray = (ctypes.c_float *16).from_buffer(viewMatrix)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrixf(matArray)
```

---

It is even possible to use a [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html?highlight=array#numpy.array)

```py
matArray = np.array(viewMatrix, dtype=np.float32)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadMatrixf(matArray)
```

Comment: You can do `matList.to_list()` in that first example instead of the list comprehension.